# Name of item in ListView

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I am trying to get name of clicked item  in ListView. I do not declaring in code names of items in ListView. User is declaring that names in running app. What i need to do is, when i click on item in ListView, in TextBlock will be name of item, whitch i clicked.

This is my simple code yet:

```
private void lstViewOfUsers_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock.Text = Name of clicked item
}
```

Comment: Share your source code

Comment: You should definitely check out MVVM if you're going to do mid-sized or larger project. With MVVM you'd expose a SelectedItem property (of the exact type) and bind it to the list view. It makes the code so much cleaner and easier to test/maintain.

Answer (score 1):

To get the text of an item in the first column then you would do :

```
TextBlock.Text = lstViewOfUsers.SelectedItems[0].Text;
```

If you wanted to get the text of a subitem it would look like this :

```
TextBlock.Text = lstViewOfUsers.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
```

Comment: And do you think it is a big error when i have 1.5 year of experience? @xRMG412

Comment: And lstViewOfUsers does not have contain a definition for "Text" and no extension method "Text"..... ?

Comment: if i write there .ToString(); there is exception

Comment: @programmersgroup4 You are using a `ListView` right? If you are there is no event called `ItemClick`. Also, what is the `View` property set to on the ListView, if you are using one.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of the clicked item by using the ItemClickEventArgs parameter

another option is to do something like this:

```
MyItemModel item = (MyItemModel)e.ClickedItem;
```

Comment: Sorry, but what i need to write instead of  "MyItemModel"? I do not unterestand